# How to get the current working directory JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I am trying to get the current working directory path using JavaScript.

When I execute from ubuntu: `$root@ubuntu:/var/test/geek# firefox /var/www/application/test.html`
I get `/var/www/application` in my alert box instead of `/var/test/geek` in my alert box.

I used the JavaScript code

```
var path=window.location.pathname
 alert(path);
```

The above code gives the path of `test.html`

Editing: Is it possible to use a Perl script? Perl-CGI?

After knowing that it is not possible from JavaScript, tried to use a Perl script:

```
my $pwd=cwd();
```

and running the Perl script from HTML.

Executing from ubuntu: `$root@ubuntu:/var/test/geek# firefox /var/www/application/test.html`

I still get `/var/www/application` in page instead of `/var/test/geek`.
Is it possible from Perl?

Comment: `window.location.pathname` returns the path of the page loaded. you cannot get the path on the user's machine (that is a security risk)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest not to rely on this. The `pathname` you got might not be the actual path. Most of the time, developers use the **routing** to hide the actual path.

The actual directory structure might be something like `"D:\Test\Test\Test.html"`, but you will be getting something different due to routing.

Comment: This should be a comment, you did not answer OP's question.